# parsing help, fscanf not reading until new line character

Tags: c, parsing, newline, scanf

Whenever i use `fscanf` to read in file contents which in this case is a country name followed by a space, country capital followed by a space, and then the population, it is read in successfully until the name of country differs such as "united arab emirates". I'm using all the advice ive been able to find and still cannot seem to have it parse until the new line operator. It instead stops scanning after united and leaves emirates for `fscand` to read into my country capital value which then throws everything off. Any suggestions will help as i am a fairly new c programmer.

```
terminal

 egypt                  cairo 81015887.000000
 madagascar             antanonariva 21926221.000000
 zimbabwe               harare 12521000.000000
 united                 arab 0.000000   
 mirates                abu 0.000000   
 habi                    8264070 0.000000   
 nited                     states 0.000000   
 ashington,                         d. 0.000000   
 .                  312642000 0.000000   
 osnia                herzegovina 0.000000
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>    //for testing within main
#include <string.h>  //for testing within main
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "headers.h"

int main()
{   
    int size, i, g;  //size of countries that will be read in
char usrC;   //user choice
FILE * fileP;
char UI[25];

Country * c[10];

ask(UI);
size = oSesame(UI, fileP, c);

if(size==0)     //if file returns as empty
{
    return 0;
}

for(g=0;g<size;g++)
{
    printf("%s %26s %-11lf\n ", c[g]->cntName, c[g]->capName, c[g]->population);

}


return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#define COUNTRY_MAX 10
#define MAX_COUNTRY_LENGTH 25
#define MAX_CAPITAL_LENGTH 25

typedef struct country
{
    char cntName[MAX_COUNTRY_LENGTH];
    char capName[MAX_CAPITAL_LENGTH];
    double population;

}Country;

int ask(char * usrTxt);
int oSesame(char usrTxt[], FILE * pFile, Country * p[]);
```

promp.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "headers.h"


int ask(char * usrTxt)
{
    int length;
    printf("Enter text file to read from :  ");
    scanf("%s", usrTxt);
    length = strlen(usrTxt);
}



int oSesame(char usrTxt[], FILE * pFile, Country * p[10])
{

int count = 0;
int savedOffset;
pFile = fopen(usrTxt, "rw");

if(pFile != NULL)
{
    savedOffset = ftell(pFile);  //save how far from beginning of file we start
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);   //seek to end of file

    if(ftell(pFile) == 0)       //if end of file is same location as beginning then file is empty
    {
        printf("File %s is empty", usrTxt);   
        return 0;           //end program

    }
    else{   
        fseek(pFile, savedOffset, SEEK_SET);        //set location indicator to beginning to begin parsing

        while(count<COUNTRY_MAX && !feof(pFile))
        {
            p[count] = (Country *) malloc(sizeof(Country));   //allocate memory for our structures since they havnt actually been declared yet just pointers to potential ones
            fscanf(pFile, "%s[^\n]", p[count]->cntName); //read in as string until newline character found in regex
            fscanf(pFile, "%s[^\n]", p[count]->capName);                
            fscanf(pFile, "%lf", &p[count]->population);
            getc(pFile);  //get new line character

            count++;
        }
        fclose(pFile);
    }
}
else
{
    printf("Error opening %s , check your spelling and try again.\n", usrTxt);
}
return count;
```

Comment: `while(count<COUNTRY_MAX && !feof(pFile))` please read the man page for `feof` for correct usage. Instead, check the return value from `fscanf` and `getc`.

Comment: If the format of your file involves variable-length strings delimited by space characters, then do you not recognize the inherent problem with those string containing internal space characters?

Comment: @JohnBollinger elaborate please

Comment: @ColinRickels, if a space character may be either data or a delimiter, then how is the program supposed to tell which any particular one is?

Comment: Note, too, that scanning to end-of-line to fill each individual field is not an appropriate approach to parsing a file in the format you described.  Your fields don't go to the end of the line, except possibly the population field.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you presented the input file, or at least a representative portion of it.

Comment: Do not use `fscanf()` for this task, use 1 or more `fgets()` and then process the string(s) read.  Should you post the _original_ text file you are trying to read, fault resistant code can be had via `fgets()`, etc.

Comment: @chux i ended up using fgets and using an additional algorithm to dispose if the trailing newline character